# Asynchronous sounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, ios6

I have the following codE:

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: _sound ofType:@ "wav"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);


    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.6f
                          delay: 0.1f
                        options: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                     animations:^{
                         [appDelegate.presstobook setFrame:  CGRectMake(136, appDelegate.window.frame.size.height - 50, 47, 47)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         presstobook = NO;
                     }
     ];
```

How can I do it so that the sound plays without affecting the rest of the code? I don't want playing the sound to pause the code at all? How can I change the code so that playing the sound occurs asynchronously without affecting the rest of the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think this will pause the code? The documentation says:

> Because sound might play for several seconds, this function is executed asynchronously.

If something in here does block, I would guess it's `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID()`. But even if this doesn't block, it's probably not a good idea to be creating one of these every time you want to play a sound, especially if you never dispose of them. You should create this once in some sort of setup, and then play it whenever you want with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()`.